Why would my basement beam be sagging so much?
From wall to wall in the basement is 16 linear feet. There is a triple 3-1/4" x 9-1/2" by 17 ft Laminated Veneer Lumber (LVL) beam. Supporting the beam is a 5-1/2" x 6" post on either end. The center of the beam sags 5/8-3/4".
Looking for any advice to help remove the sag and not have a center support post.
This home is about 60 years old. Single level.

3/4" sag, can you move the joists upwards to compensate?  But before that is the floor (above the LVL)  level now?  Stuff bends, this is not always a problem.

Not an engineer and do not know LVL that well, but 9 1/2 seems a bit on the small side for a 16ft span(unless engineer designed).  Is it just the three LVL beam sagging or the joists/floor also?

If it's a triple 3-1/4" x 9-1/2" that's closer to six 2x10 side-by-side "nominal lumber equivalent." And probably should have been done deeper, rather than so wide, but the usual problem is that "pennies must be pinched" and making the basement 8" taller costs money, so a sub-optimal beam depth is chosen to maintain headroom in the basement. Replacing the beam with steel seems like the most likely no-post solution, but will be expensive and still requires the engineer to figure out what steel beam and how it can be done. While a post is much, much cheaper.

That's a fair amount of sag. I'd also want to do something about it. I'm not sure whether it's a failure risk, but it's undoubtedly causing wall cracks and door alignment issues above. The reason is simply because it's not tall enough for the load. Height has a much greater impact on stiffness than width.
You have two general options, assuming that maintaining current head clearance is a priority:

Replace the beam with steel. A properly-sized I-beam of the same height will be more rigid and less prone to sagging than the wood (at least until fire breaks out). You can often support the joists with temporary walls on the slab and slide a new beam in through a temporary hole in the foundation.

Install an intermediate post. This would require opening your basement slab and pouring a suitable footing (say 24x24x10"). The slab is not a suitable footing, and it's unlikely that there's something below the slab now. An adjustable steel column would allow you to gradually return the sagging beam to its intended position.


There are other possibilities, such as replacing the beam with a wooden one having a taller section (which could be inset into the joist height as a top-mount or flush beam), but you haven't provided enough information for answers in that vein.

Why it is sagging is either 1) it is in the process of failing, 2) it was under-specified, or 3) something above it has changed since installation.
How to fix without a pole is almost certainly going to require a structural engineer to specify a new beam or beams.
